# Get item name from Arraylist and compare

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array list which is declared as

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

In the below screenshot you can find out the array items in it:

[image]

Now how do I get that string and compare to my existing string value

Suppose I have a string name `"inbox"`, how do I get the `title` named `inbox`.

```
public interface Item {

    public boolean isSection();

}
```

SectionItem

```
public class SectionItem implements Item{

    private final String title;

    public SectionItem(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Can anyone suggest me a better way of handling this?

Comment: Post code of `Item` class.

Comment: `Suppose I have a string name "inbox", how do I get the title named inbox.` Can you elaborate? Do you mean how do you get the `Item` instance with that specific title?

Comment: @copeg- I mean if I have a string value predefined I need to compare with that title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using, `get(int index)` method of ArrayList.
which Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

In your case

```
String itemTitle = items.get(index).getTitle(); // Here index represent position of item you want to get title from current array list
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to use a cast:

`String sectiontitle = ((SectionItem)items.get(index)).getTitle();`

Though, in my opinion, you should have a  `String title;` as a member of your interface `Item`

Answer (score 0):

Just get the title by accesing the index, and if you are comparing strings you shuold use equals:

```
return items.get(index).getTitle().equals(myString);
```

if you want to iterate through the array do a for loop:

```
for(int index = 0; index < items.length() -1; index++) {
}
```